# URL redirecting using .htaccess in Cakephp 2.0

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am using Cakephp 2.0 and my website domain name is www.sample.com , If I try to access sample.com (with out www) then its going to www.sample.com this is fine. But My problem is my domain consists of lot of pages
for example :

```
> http://www.sample.com/users/login
> http://www.sample.com/users/add
```

If I access the above url like http://sample.com/users/login then it redirect to

```
>  http://www.sample.com/index.php?url=users/login
```

but it needs to redirect to

```
   http://www.sample.com/users/login
```

I already written the following code .htaccess file(before the app folder) to redirect

```
Rewritecond %{http_host} ^sample.com [NC]
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.sample.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Inside webroot folder I have one .htacces file that contain the following code
may be that is the problem I think

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you trying to always remove www or always keep www? This will add it:

```
## Add www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

## CakePHP
RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
```

Comment: i need www always.. if they not put www also it need to go to www.sample.com

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the next rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sample.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.sample.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

on app/webroot/.htaccess file, not on app's folder .htaccess. It works perfectly for me.